# R Shiny: Module and observeEvent and id map dont match

Tags: r, shiny, module

I have a problem with observeEvent. the id map in the html code is id1-map-map. He doesn't like the -.
I also tested map-map but it doesn't work.
How to do ?

in ui.R

```
fluidPage(
       module_gisUI(id="id1")
)
```

in module UI

```
#####  Function for module UI*
moduleUI <- function(id) {
  ns <- NS(id)
  
  # Sidebar with a ui for grabbing mapedit data
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      actionButton(ns('save'), 'Save'),
      br(),br(),
      actionButton(ns("rnorm"), "Load"),
      plotOutput(ns("plot1")))
    ,
    
    # add map: module mapedit
    mainPanel(
      editModUI(ns("map"))
    )
  )
  
}
```

in module : observeEvent(input$id1-map-map_marker_click

```
##### Function for module server logic
module_gis <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  #map
  map<-leaflet() %>%
    addTiles()
    
  #module mapedit*
  edits <- callModule(
    editMod,
    leafmap = map,
    id = "map"
  )
  
  #load
  observeEvent(input$rnorm, {
    
    leafletProxy("map-map",data=datapoints)%>% 
      addMarkers(~LongSEC, ~LatSEC)
    
  })
  
  #observeEvent(input$id1-map-map_marker_click, { 

 # good solution
  observeEvent(input$`map-map_marker_click`, { 
    p <- input$`map-map_marker_click`
    print(p)
  })
  
  
}
```

Comment: Without a complete minimal reproducible example (here: running shiny app) it's a bit hard to say. A few remarks: 1. if you use variable names with forbidden characters, you need to wrap them in backticks: ``input$`id1-map-map_marker_click`` 2. Within a server, you usually don't need to prefix the id with which the module is called, so just try ``input$`map-map_marker_click``` (sorry, markdown doesn't want as I want, wrap the part after $ in backticks)

Comment: Thanks, removing id and with backticks it works !